# Parse JsonString to JsonObject in Java

Tags: java, json

I have the following String :

```
{
    "response": true,
    "model_original_id": "5acea0b5:1431fde5d6e:-7fff",
    "model_new_id": 500568,
    "model_new_version": 1,
    "reload": true,
    "idsModelProperties": [{
        "key": "creation_date",
        "value": "2013-12-23"
    },
    {
        "key": "state",
        "value": 1,
        "displayValue": "Analisi"
    }],
    "idsNodes": [],
    "idsConnectors": [],
    "idsNodesProperties": []
}
```

and i need to parse it as a JSONObject. I tried to use 
quickjson but it gives me an exception when it tries to parse an emty string .
This is what i tried :

```
JsonParserFactory factory=JsonParserFactory.getInstance();
JSONParser parser=factory.newJsonParser();
Map jsonData=parser.parseJson(response_output);
```

Exception:
**Exception in thread "main" com.json.exceptions.JSONParsingException: @Key-Hierarchy::root/idsNodes[0]/    @Key::  Value is expected but found empty...@Position::256**

Any idea?

Comment: And what empty string?

Comment: Is the string empty or null ? If it fails on "empty" string only parse if non-empty string is given.

Comment: It looks like quickjson cannot handle empty json arrays. Try using a different parsing library.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/issues/detail?id=4

Comment: Any idea which library should I use?

Comment: GSON https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ can handle empty arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give you an alternative since it looks like `quick-json` has trouble parsing empty json arrays. Check out [`Gson`](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

```
String json = "{ \"response\": true, \"model_original_id\": \"5acea0b5:1431fde5d6e:-7fff\", \"model_new_id\": 500568, \"model_new_version\": 1, \"reload\": true, \"idsModelProperties\": [{ \"key\": \"creation_date\", \"value\": \"2013-12-23\" }, { \"key\": \"state\", \"value\": 1, \"displayValue\": \"Analisi\" }], \"idsNodes\": [], \"idsConnectors\": [], \"idsNodesProperties\": []}";
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(json);
```

`JsonElement` is an abstract class. Its sub types are `JsonArray`, `JsonNull`, `JsonObject` and `JsonPrimitive`. In the example above, the actual instance is a `JsonObject` because your json `String` is a json object. It internally contains a `LinkedTreeMap` but you don't really need access to it. You can access the different json objects directly on the `JsonElement`.

Comment: In fact I get the json string dinamically... 
So I cannot do escape of " manually ...

Comment: @user3107262 That's just an example to make it run. You don't need to escape anything if it's already in the String. Escaping is just for String literals.

Answer (score 2):

While the author of the question has already accepted an answer, someone else might be searching for the same issue. I've fixed the issues I know of with quick-json in https://code.google.com/p/quick-json/issues/detail?id=11